# Updating Values on Excel Worksheet While Macro Runs

Tags: excel, vba

Some of the values on my excel sheet are affected during the process of running my macro. Based on those values, I would in turn get other values. 
For example:

1 0 1 0

0 1 1 0

my last line should be a sum of the above lines (using the excel function on the worksheet =sum(...):

1 1 2 0

I would like to find the minimum of this last line and update the above 2 lines to:

1 0 1 1

0 1 1 0

I have already gotten this process to work. However, when I loop it, the values are based on the existing values on the spreadsheet (does not change according to the process, hence the minimum value never changes). Is there an existing syntax or command that will allow me to update values WHILE the macro runs through the excel sheet so that my code is able to read the updated values instead?

Thank you.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do, and you've posted no actual code, so it's unlikely you'll get much response.

Comment: Sorry, my issue here is that I am unclear if there exists a command or a syntax to update values while my macro is running through my excel file.

Comment: You can use `Worksheet.Calculate` to force the sheet to update whenever you need to ensure the formulas are up to date.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried your suggestion and it is working! However, is there a way that I can see the result changing on the worksheet itself with each update?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, earlier, I have turned screenupdating to false. It has now been set to true and the spreadsheet is updating as the code runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Calculate
```

Will update values within vba when 
ScreenUpdating is set to false.